# Plot custom functions in each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I've got some custom functions which plot the results of some analysis. I want to show each plot in a subplot of a figure, something like

```
---------------------------
|   Plot 1   |   Plot 2   |
|            |            |
---------------------------
|   Plot 3   |   Plot 4   |
|            |            |
---------------------------
```

Here's an MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_sin():
    x = np.linspace(0, 10)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('Just a sine curve')

def plot_int():
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
    y = np.sin(x) / x
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('Looks like an interference pattern')

def plot_hist():
    x = np.random.normal(0.2, 0.05, 1000)
    plt.hist(x)
    plt.title('Oh look, it\'s a histogram')

def plot_sin_cos():
    x = np.linspace(-3*np.pi, 3*np.pi, 1000)
    y = np.sin(x) / np.cos(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('Yet another siney plot')

plot_sin()
plot_int()
plot_hist()
plot_sin_cos()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax[0, 0].plot_sin()
ax[1, 0].plot_int()
ax[0, 1].plot_hist()
ax[1, 1].plot_sin_cos()
```

but of course `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plot_sin'`. How can I have each of my functions plotted in a separate subplot?

Comment: Pass each function an `ax` parameter. And change each function to use the [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
# pass the axis here and the other functions as well
def plot_sin(ax):
    x = np.linspace(0, 10)
    y = np.sin(x)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.set_title('Just a sine curve')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
plot_sin(ax[0,0])
```